# What's the best way to handle session timeouts in ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, django

Consider this Django view which will get a list of items associated to the current user:

```
@login_required
def list_items(request, page_number=0):
    items = Paginator(request.user.items, 5).page(page_number).object_list
    return HttpResponse(cjson.encode(items))
```

Obviously, it wants to use the `login_required` decorator, to restrict access to the view for logged-in users.

What does `login_required` do when a non-authenticated user tries to access the view? It returns a `HttpResponseRedirect` toward `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

Consider this JavaScript code, which calls the view:

```
var getPage = function(pageNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/list_items/" + pageNumber + "/",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#list_container").html(formatData(data))
        }
    });
};
```

Suppose `settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60` seconds.

If a user goes to page 1, reads it for 61 seconds, then clicks on the button for page 2, Django's [`login_required`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L36) decorator will detect that the session is no longer active, and will return a `HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)`, which will cause the `success` callback to get a HTML login page instead of the JSON-encoded list.

[This is where it happens.](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L111)
[It's called by `user_passes_test` here.](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L30)

What's the best way to handle this?

Here's a few things I've thought of:

`1.` The `success` callback should check the response, and see if it gets a login page, by whatever means (check if content-type is html, check contents, etc). But this means that we have to wrap all AJAX calls with a callback wrapper like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/list_items/" + pageNumber + "/",
        success: sessionExpiryCallbackWrapper(function(data) {
            $("#list_container").html(formatData(data))
        })
    });
```

But this is ugly, and developers might forget to do this everywhere.

`2.` Use `$.ajaxComplete` to handle all requests.

```
    $.ajaxComplete(globalCompleteCallback);
    $.ajax({
        success: successCallback,
        complete: completeCallback
    });
```

But this is the call order:

```
    successCallback(); // success is called before complete
    completeCallback();
    globalCompleteCallback(); // this is called after the local callback
```

So we only catch the redirect, after successCallback has failed, and possibly with JS errors due to the invalid data it received.

`3.` If [`login_required`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L36) would return 403 on AJAX requests:

```
    if not user.is_authenticated():
        if request.is_ajax():
            # send 403 to ajax calls
            return HttpResponse403("you are not logged in")
        else:
            # regular code path
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

But [`login_required`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L36) just uses [`user_passes_test`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L9) which doesn't do this.

[`user_passes_test`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L9) has a lot of functionality in there, so it's not such a good idea to reimplement it.

What's the best way to handle the timeouts for AJAX calls?

Comment: Sorry but I am going to go all philosophical on you. The original intent of session timeouts was to prevent the server from holding significant resources or having to do expensive operations on each request. We now have client-side frameworks doing most of the work. So why are short session timeouts even needed?

Comment: @DaveMethvin Session timeouts are needed to narrow the window for session hijacking be it a) on the wire/air or b) physically by someone going to someone else's computer after they've gone AFK a bit.

Comment: That problem seems pretty easy to solve though, just have the client session timeouts be shorter than the server ones. If that is the case it should be really rare for the client to ever make a request that finds itself at a server without a valid session. Plus that means you can put up a nice looking client-initiated "your session has timed out" message.

Comment: @DaveMethvin Good thinking, but if you have a page that shows static content and only gets refreshed when the user performs some action other than interacting with the static content, then it would be nice to show a login form and retry the AJAX call that was needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would handle it by having your session timeout method check whether or not it is being requested with AJAX. If it is ajax, return a `401` not authorized(or 403 forbidden or whatever status makes sense) status code with an empty json string. Next, in your javascript, bind a global `ajaxError` handler that checks for that status code and handles it appropriately.

Comment: This is what I did eventually, but I had to write a new `login_required` decorator to `return HttpResponse40{1,3} if request.is_ajax() else RedirectToLoginPage()` rather than just redirect either way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like http://amplifyjs.com/ that lets you write a nice wrapper for your AJAX calls and then use its [data mapping](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/#data_mapping) feature to check if the user is still logged in before doing the AJAX call.

This way you can have a client-side timer that sets the user to logged-out status and provides a hint so the login check doesn't need to be done before every AJAX call.

Alternatively you can use a custom [decoder](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/#decoders) which asks the user to log in and retries the AJAX call if the user was logged out. It would need to store all the xhr data and callbacks it gets called with until the user logs in.