# Ajax call to django @login_required view returns login page if user had logged out

Tags: jquery, django

If wrap a view function in @login_required and call it using $.ajax({...}) and the user has logged out (from another tab for example), the success() call back is called and the data is the content of the login page redirect.

Is there a way for the @login_required decorator to return an error code if it's an ajax request rather than a redirect, so I can correctly redirect in javascript?

This post ([What's the best way to handle session timeouts in ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694693/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-session-timeouts-in-ajax-requests)) indicated I would have to write my on @login_required decorator... Isn't there a way to handle this within the core django?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator. It can be set to return a 403 error code instead of a login page redirect.

Comment: Unfortunately that will only check .has_perm() rather than .is_authenticated().  I've looked through the django source code and it looks like I'll just have to write my own.